# Android Automation : Espresso and UiAutomator

Tags: android, build.gradle, android-testing, android-espresso, android-uiautomator

I am getting dirty with Espresso and UiAutomator. Well, I did make some progress and then stuck.

**What I have** : Espresso & UiAutomator test cases, but as two projects.

**What I want to do** : I want to combine these two test cases as a single project and want to execute both the test cases at the same time.

**Problem** : When I include both the dependencies

`androidTestCompile 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:2.2.1',
androidTestCompile 'com.android.support.test.uiautomator:uiautomator-v18:2.1.1'`

in my build.gradle file, the test cases were not able to resolve them and showing compile time errors saying **@RunWith(AndroidJUnit4.class) isn't recognized.**, **create/import class Espresso**, **created/import class UiAutomator** etc.,. Basically app isn't able to resolve the espresso & uiautomator dependencies.

Any ideas ? Did anyone come across such situation. Thanks in advance.

Comment: It's not clear what you're asking. What specific compilation errors are you getting?

Comment: @AllenHair - I edited my question. Please take a look. Thanks!

Comment: Have you installed the Android Support Repository via the SDK Manager?

Comment: @AllenHair I guess so, I am using Android Studio 2.0 beta 6. When I open Android SDK Manager, it didn't showed up Android Support Repo to install/update, its not listed under Extras. I read somewhere in the SO that Android Support Repo is moved to my m2repository on my machine. When I browsed through the path I found all the .jars of Espresso & UiAutomator. BTW, the same test cases are executing individually, I mean as separate projects. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Espresso & UiAutomator can be used together, they're independent from each other. Did you add dependencies for:

```
androidTestCompile 'com.android.support.test:runner:0.5'  
androidTestCompile 'com.android.support.test:rules:0.5'
```

Also please have a look at our samples on github: https://github.com/googlesamples/android-testing

It might also be a result of https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=200952 which is fixed in beta7.

Comment: To expand on the original question - I have a project called "TestCases", in that under "androidTest" folder I have two classes EspressoTestCases.java(contains only espresso based test cases) and UiAutomatorTestCases.javases(contains only uiautomator based test cases). I added all the necessary dependencies. When I try to compile them, am getting compile time error as mentioned in the original question. 
Could you pls confirm what am trying to do is possible or not ? Thanks!